# In a Ruby method "def initialize(params)" what does "params||={}" do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, initialization, arguments

I have this inside my Rails Model "InvoiceSearch":

```
class InvoiceSearch
  attr_reader :date_from, :date_to

 def initialize(params)
    params||={}
    @date_from = parsed_date(params[:date_from], 7.days.ago.to_date.to_s)
    @date_to = parsed_date(params[:date_to], Date.today.to_s)
  end
```

What am I doing by saying `params||={}`?

What does

```
@date_to = parsed_date(params[:date_to], Date.today.to_s)"
```

do exactly?

Definition of 'parsed_date':

```
private
  def parsed_date(date_string, default)
    Date.parse(date_string)
  rescue ArgumentError, TypeError
    default
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

So `params ||= {}` is equivalent to `params = params || {}`. In Ruby `nil` is considered false. So if `params` is `nil` (or `false`) it will get set to `{}`. That's important in the code below because if `params` is `nil` then `params[:date_from]` will cause an error. But if `params` is an empty hash, i.e. `{}` then `params[:date_from]` will return `nil` and won't cause an error.

Based on the definition of `parsed_date` it will attempt to parse `date_string` but if `date_string` is nil or an invalid date (e.g. `Feb 30, 2015`) then it will throw an error. The `rescue ArgumentError, TypeError` handles those errors and will return `default`.

If your program expects `@date_from` and `@date_to` to be `Date` objects, then your calls should not include the `.to_s` for `default` because that will cause e.g. `@date_from` to be set to the string to e.g. `"Wed, 18 Feb 2015"` rather than the actual `Date` object corresponding to today's date.

So in summary, the line `@date_to = parsed_date(params[:date_to], Date.today.to_s)` will attempt to parse the date given by the parameter `date_to` and convert it to a `Date` object, but if the parameter wasn't specified (so `params[:date_to]` is `nil`), it was `false` or it was an invalid date, then `@date_to` will get assigned to the default value, in your case, the string of today's date.

Comment: "if params is nil it will get set to {}". That's close. If params is nil or *false* it will get set to `{}`.

Comment: @draffensperger You are correct, 'parsed_date' is not a Rails method. i edited my question to include its definition, I apologize for initially omitting that.

Comment: So, if I'm understanding this correctly.... if `params` arguments (`date_to` and `date_from`) are left blank by the user, then `params` is empty (`nil`), meaning that `parsed_date(params[:date_to], Date.today.to_s)` only outputs `Date.today.to_s`, right?

If that's true, how does Rails know to ignore `Date.today.to_s` when `params` is not `nil`? What part of the code, or part of Rails, makes the default `Date.today.to_s` get ignored?